# write unit test using gmock

Tags: googletest, googlemock

Consider the case as below

```
class A
{
   public:
      bool Init()
      {
         bool ret = false;
         /* code */
         return ret;
      }
};

A a_obj;

class B
{
   public:
      bool Foo()
      { 
         if(a_obj.Init())
         {
            cout<< "X" ;
         }
         else
         {
            cout<< "Y" ;
         }
      }
}

class MockA
{
   public:
      METHOD0(Init, bool());
};

TEST(InitTest, CallFoo)
{
MockA mockobj;
B b_obj;
/* ???*/
}
```

I want to write 2 unit test cases by using mock to simulate the return value of Init

1. return value of Init is true whch prints X
2. return value of Init is false which prints Y.

I do not want to keep the A object as member of B, i want to keep it as a global vartiable.
How do i go about writing these tests ?

Answer (score 1):

`A` doesn't have to be a member of `B` - it can be passed as the parameter to  `Foo()` with `a_obj` as the default:

```
// A definition as before
A a_obj;

class B
{
   public:
      bool Foo(A& a = a_obj)
      { 
         if(a.Init())
         {
            cout<< "X" ;
         }
         else
         {
            cout<< "Y" ;
         }
      }
}
```

But you'll have to make `Init` a virtual method (and add virtual dtor to A most probably) and then have `MockA` derive from `A` or use [hi-perf DI](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) and make `Foo` a template method or whole class `B` depending on a template.